# Outlook Add-in VSTO install

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin, installshield-le, outlook-2016

I have written a VSTO for Outlook with a formregion for meeting/appointmentitems in VS 2015.
I deploy this to our desktop computers using ClickOnce.

I would like to use the Windows Installer to install the VSTO for laptops because when I use ClickOnce and the laptop uses Outlook when not connected to the corporate network, the add-in is disabled.
I assume this is because it cannot reach the internal ClickOnce publish location, eventhough the deployment should not check for updates.

I have followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2017) to create an installer for the addin.

I followed the all-users steps and the files are installed to the local computer and the registry keys are being created but the Add-in is not loaded in Outlook and it even is not showing up in the list of Addins in Outlook.

Anyone who has had similar issues and knows how to solve this problem? It's driving me crazy for the past 2 days.

Comment: There is no such central repository. Your addin most likely gets disabled on startup because of a run-time error.

Comment: You have got it correct @DmitryStreblechenko, there was a runtime error that occured. I was able to see the error using the system environment variables VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 1 and VSTO_LOGALERTS = 1. Then a message popped up that there was an issue and logfile identified what was the problem.

How can I accept your reply as the answer to my question?

Comment: I reposted the comment as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such central repository. Your addin most likely gets disabled on startup because of a run-time error.